# Android Accessibilty Service: onAccessibilityEvent() Method isn't fired all the time

Tags: android, service, accessibilityservice

**Preface**:
**Device:** *Nexus 5, Android Lollipop*

> Put simply, My App does capture the Accessibility events but capture rate is only
>   around 93%.

This might look good but it is unacceptable for the kind of functionality my App is designed for.

My code:

```
    @Override
    public void onServiceConnected() {

    AccessibilityServiceInfo info = new AccessibilityServiceInfo();
    info.notificationTimeout = 0;
    info.eventTypes = AccessibilityEvent.TYPE_WINDOW_STATE_CHANGED;
    info.feedbackType = AccessibilityServiceInfo.FEEDBACK_GENERIC;
    info.packageNames = new String[] { "com.android.phone" };

    setServiceInfo(info);
    }

    public void onAccessibilityEvent(AccessibilityEvent x) {
        Log.e("Event", "Occurred");
    }
```

**Question:**

1. If you have worked with **Accessibility Services** before have you observed something similar?
2. If missing events is a norm, is my capture rate poor ?
3. If you overcame this issue, **Please Please answer this, I'll buy you a pizza anywhere you are on earth**......Seriously !

Comment: Could you define what you mean by "missing"? What type of events are missing? Did you set `notificationTimeout` to 0 in your service meta-data?

Comment: alanv, I did set notificationTimeout to 0. What you can call a miss is, simply the absence of a Log Tag in LogCat which I output when the event is fired.

Comment: Besides, if I use Monkey by Android Debug Bridge, the capture rate gets worse.

Comment: What type of events are missing?

Comment: TYPE_WINDOW_STATE_CHANGED

Comment: Could you add the code that you're using to detect that the event has been fired and to detect that is has been received? It's possible that there's a bug in the framework, but it could be a bug in your code. Hard to tell without more context.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/73454/discussion-between-time-traveller-and-alanv).